# nestjs how to handle error in onApplicationBootstrap()

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

i have a @Injectable TowerService method running in onApplicationBootstrap()

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(TasksService.name)

  constructor(private towerService: TowerService) {}
  onApplicationBootstrap() {
    this.towerService.sendTowerJob()
  }
}
```

and in TowerService , sendTowerJob() method throw an exception

```
async sendTowerJob() {
  throw new HttpException(`error`, 500)
}
```

i have tried using Filter Or Interceptor to handle error globally , but i found error will be handle globally only when service method running in Controller. and its won't be handle globally while method running in onApplicationBootstrap(), or some Cron Methods (just like below).

```js
@Injectable()
export class TasksService implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(TasksService.name)

  constructor(private towerService: TowerService) {}
  onApplicationBootstrap() {
    this.towerService.sendTowerJob() // filter and interceptor will not handle error in this method
  }

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_5_SECONDS)
  async handleCron() {
    this.towerService.sendTowerJob() // filter and interceptor will not handle error in this method
  }
}
```

```js
@Controller('tower')
export class TowerController {
  constructor(private readonly towerService: TowerService) {}

  @Get()
  async test() {
    this.towerService.sendTowerJob() // filter and interceptor will handle error in this method
  }
}
```

so how can i handle error globally in some methods like onApplicationBootstrap() or Cron Methods ? not only in Controller .  thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

You can implement error handling locally with a `try/catch` statement, possibly even build an error handling service that takes in the error and manages it as necessary

**OR**

you can implement a `process.on('unhandledRejection')` and `process.on('uncaughtException')` event handlers and have a unified error handler that way.

These errors happen outside of the request lifecycle, which is what the exception filter is there to help with. Generally, these methods should be self contained and handle whatever errors may happen.